# How to identify vulnerable code in an IoT node?

Tags: security, iot

As part of an on-going project of mine, my task is to  identify instructions in a code which are vulnerable to tampering.

The code would be running on an IoT device. And the identification of instructions can be from either the source code or just the executable(with no source code).

Does anyone know about some tools or techniques?

In a nutshell, how to automatically locate security-sensitive code?

EDIT: I believe now I have come to understand my task better. I do not have to use a tool to protect but devise a technique of my own to protect my code statements( written in C Language) which are vulnerable. Especially Anti-debugging statements. 
Are there any heuristics to find out the vulnerable statements in the code. like authentication points and Anti-Debugging checks?

Comment: Be careful with that kind of question. SO is primarly a site for Q&A and not suggestions / opinion-based answers. Think more of questions like "How does this tool work?" instead of "What tool should I use?" I know it can be frustrating sometimes

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your suggestion. But I do need to find the answer to the question I have asked. Even a starting point would be great.

Comment: Oh I can't help you at all with that, this is not at all my area, I was just reviewing "first posts" from new users. I do hope someone will be able to help you, but I can't.

Comment: I know that. I wasn't asking you to answer my question. May be I need to write more clearly. It's just that I am new here and don't know all the guidelines and proper ways to ask a question. Also, I have seen a number of posts asking for suggestions and they have been answered. So, didn't want to edit my question too much.  But, Thank you!

Comment: As it stands I think your question is clear enough and you just need enough luck for someone to answer it :)

Comment: Haha! Thank you. I hope SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the software runs on a device is not different than software running on a web server or local/cloud computer.

What you might want to do is look at all the individual components in your setup that might expose a vulnerability.

The image below is a representation that I often use for describing a connected product from the highest level.

It contains:

1. The device (often running C or C++ code)
2. The connection to the cloud (like, https or a messaging service)
3. The API to the cloud (often a RESTful API)
4. The software on the cloud itself

[image: The four steps in a connected device]

You can go through these ones by one and identify what might be wrong. As a rule of thumb, you can always try to find the spot where an outside connection is made.

Following those four steps

1. Check if the code can be tempered with before an outside connection is made. If your code is compiled and makes an outside connection, try to find an alternative that you can validate.
2. Check certificates, messaging protocols etc. Makes sure all connections are following safety standards.
3. Make sure your API follows [proper](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) RESTful security measures.
4. Validate the software in the cloud, check certificates and use something like [OATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Last, check services like https://www.checkmarx.com/

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I have made an EDIT to the question. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: To answer your question in the edit. The heuristics you have are the known tools (like https://www.checkmarx.com/) and reading _a lot_ of blogs on the topic (like: http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/). You are in charge on how it will work. If you like my answer, please select it as the answer :-)

Comment: Okay. Using a tool as a heuristic implies checking its documentation, right?Also, thanx for the link of the blog you shared. Can you suggest some other blogs as well. I am reading about it but I find some of them unsuitable for a beginner and/or not specific to what I need. My task is to find out vulnerable statements and give them as input to a tool  developed for protecting statements.